# Is there a way to retrieve the custom labels that the user has created for CNContact properties in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, contacts-framework

Is there a way to retrieve the custom labels that the user has created for CNContact properties in iOS? I know that properties of CNContact objects are often of the generic type CNLabeledValue. The label property of that type of object gives the label portion of the object.

Here is a two screenshots of my iPhone screen showing the UI for creating a custom label. As you see in the first screenshot, it says "Add Custom Label" to allow the user to create a custom label for phone number properties. In the second screenshot, the UI is allowing the user to create the custom label.

[image: select label]

[image: create custom label]

Comment: Are you looking for an API that gives you the list of custom labels the user has created or do you want a specific custom label assigned to a phone number?

Comment: And what does the code you posted have to do with your question?

Comment: @rmaddy I need to first thing you mentioned -- a way to get all the custom labels that the user has created.

Sorry about the code. I got an error saying that the question was not up to standard when I tried to post the question, so I put more content in. I would have preferred not to include that code in the post. Here, I'll try to edit the post and delete the code.